# undefined local variable or method `http' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby

File: `nethttp.rb`

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

uri = URI('http://localhost/events',:headers => headers)
res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
puts res.body if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

I'm receiving the error:

> undefined local variable or method `http' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: I try to consume API by the library nethttp, but i can't fix this error :

Comment: You are using a local variable named `http`, but did not set it anywhere.

Comment: `http` is not defined. That's what the error tells you. I'm not sure what you were expecting to happen here, but perhaps you meant to put something like `http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)` **BELOW** the `uri= ...` line of code? And then use `http.get` instead of `Net::HTTP.get_response`?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the local variable `http` which is not declared anywhere in the code. If you want to create an instance of Net::HTTP you need to use the "new" method:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

# URI only takes one argument!
uri = URI('http://localhost/events')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri)
# not sure what this is supposed to do since you're requesting a 
# HTTP uri and not HTTPS
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
# ...
```

But you might want to consider using `Net::HTTP.start` which opens a connection and yields it to the block:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
uri = URI('http://localhost/events')

# Opens a persisent connection to the host
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, verify_mode: OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
  headers = { "X-FOO" => "Bar" }
  request = http.get(uri)
  headers.each do |key, value|
    request[key] = value
  end
  response = http.request(request)
  # consider using a case statement
  if response.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
     puts response.body 
  else
     # handle errors
  end
end
```

Comment: On a side note its pretty rediculous that Net::HTTP in 2021 still does not have methods where you can pass a hash of headers to be added to a request. Its probally the most awkward part of the entire Ruby StdLib.